# prefetching pd (4 double) into __m256d register

Tags: avx, prefetch

I want to prefetch some data using AVX. I was checking the Intel IntrisicsGuide (https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/) but there exists only the _mm_prefetch(...) for SSE. Does anyone know a workaround for AVX?
Update 19.02.15:
Maybe i am misunderstanding the purpose of prefetching. So i wanted to describe the problem a bit more in detail:

```
#include <x86intrin.h>
...
__m128 x0 = ...;
...
// doing some vector operations ...
for (int i=0; i<ndiv4; ++i) {
    _mm_prefetch((char*) y+4*i+8, _MM_HINT_NTA ); //prefetch data fro two iteratrions later
    __m128 x1 = _mm_load_ps(x+4*i); // aligned load
    __m128 x2 = _mm_mul_ps(x0,x1); // x0 defined earlier
    _mm_store_ps(x+4*i,x2); // store aligned back
}
```

(i know that the prefetch might not necessarily help in this case).
My question is, if or how i could do it using __m256d registers and pd respectively?

Comment: Prefetching doesn't generally refer to loading values into registers. If you want to load it into a register, then use the appropriate instruction to load it into a register. Prefetching intends to get the values from main memory into one or more levels of your cache hierarchy so that the subsequent instruction to load it into a register doesn't have to wait as long and cause pipeline stalls. In that sense, prefetching really has nothing to do with SSE vs AVX, and is only "for SSE" in the sense that the prefetch instructions were introduced as part of SSE...

Comment: @twalberg thanks for the hint! I changed my question therefore.

Comment: @LeoW. If you prefetch, you pull data into CPU cache. The cache then loads a full `cache line`, which is hardware dependent and can be found using `CPUID`, if I'm not mistaken. You require to load 32B to cache, most CPUs with AVX would have 64, 128 or even more bytes in a single `cache line`. Thus you usually prefetch more data than you need anyway. In the end, I don't understand this question as you show SSE code and want it to be AVX code, while the question is about prefetch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the literal answer to "how i could do it using __m256d registers and pd respectively?" would be this:

```
for (int i=0; i<ndiv8; ++i) {
    _mm_prefetch((char*) y+8*i+16, _MM_HINT_NTA ); //prefetch data fro two iteratrions later
    __m256 x1 = _mm_load_pd(x+8*i); // aligned load
    __m256 x2 = _mm_mul_pd(x0,x1); // x0 defined earlier
    _mm_store_pd(x+8*i,x2); // store aligned back
}
```

Changing "_ps" to "_pd", "128" to "256", and "4" to "8" as appropriate. Given that you're consuming data twice as fast, though, the prefetch stride might need to be adjusted a bit, but that's a bit of a black art that's best accomplished with benchmarking...